# Pushing to multidimensional object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to end up with an object like:

```
{"Red 1":53,"Blue 2":26,"Green 3":25}
```

From the following example:

Was trying to push the data from inside .each to the object, but it being multidimensional, i'm not sure how to accomplish this:

```
//html
<div class="test">
    <div class="color">Red 1</div>
    <div class="value">53</div>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <div class="color">Blue 2</div>
    <div class="value">26</div>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <div class="color">Green 3</div>
    <div class="value">25</div>
</div>

//js
var dataPoints = {}; 
var colorTitle = '';
var colorValue = '';

$('.test').each(function(index) {
    colorTitle = $(this).find('.color').html();
    colorValue = $(this).find('.value').html();
    dataPoints.push({colorTitle:colorValue});
});
```

The code above clearly does not work, but I wanted to demonstrate basically what I am trying to do.

Tried this approach as well:

```
dataPoints[index][colorTitle] = colorValue;
```

Which doesn't work either. Probably missing something all together, but any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using an array? It has sequential indices and `.push` built-in. You can have it working with `var dataPoints = []` http://jsfiddle.net/CLy6B/6/

Comment: @Esailija, OP wants to end up like this `{"Red 1":53,"Blue 2":26,"Green 3":25}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do it:

```
var data = {};
$(".test").each(function() {
   var key = $(this).find(".color").text();
   var value = $(this).find(".value").text();

   data[key] = value;
};
```

Comment: no need to call jQuery twice on this... you could call it only once and cache it like so: var $this = $(this);

Answer (score 3):

Use proper key/value assignment when dealing with objects. Objects don't have a `push` method.

```
$('.test').each(function(index) {
    dataPoints[$(this).find(".color").text()] = $(this).find(".value").text();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually your not so far from getting it right, but think it as an object and not as an array -

```
var dataPoints = new Object(); 
var colorTitle = '';
var colorValue = '';

$('.test').each(function(index) {
    colorTitle = $(this).find('.color').html();
    colorValue = $(this).find('.value').html();
    dataPoints[colorTitle] = colorValue;
});

//test it!
alert(JSON.stringify(dataPoints));
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, just noticed what you want to have as your final result

Answer (score 2):

Its not multidimensional. Its not even an array.

`push` is used for arrays.

In an `object` you can add a key/value  like `obj["key"]= value` or `obj.key = value`.

So, try this

```
var dataPoints = {};  
$('.test').each(function(index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    dataPoints[$this.find('.color').html()]= $this.find('.value').html();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a close parenthesis for the `each()` function. Also an object `{}` doesn't have a push method.

If you want to maintain a list of elements, use an array `[]`.